# how to trigger angular parsers without inputing anything in the field

Tags: parsing, angularjs, triggers

As the subject states, how do I trigger the actions to take place inside a

```
modelController.$parsers(...)
```

without user input... the only way I can think of is wrapping them inside a function and call it, but is there a better way to trigger

```
**//pseudo
$(modelController).trigger('just got dirty');**
```

the reason I would need this is to trigger the input field to validate itself on submitting page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found a way to solve this - just call the parsers with the model value:

```
angular.forEach(ngModel.$parsers, function (parser) {
    parser(ngModel.$viewValue);
});
```

It`s so simple, and it seems to be the most correct solution.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me (version 1.2.29) — thanks! Why is this simple answer not more widespread? For a slight improvement on the answer, use a native `for` loop instead of `angular.forEach`, check the `name` property of the parser and only retrigger what you want instead of everything (if applicable), and `break` the loop once you've triggered what you want. These are only micro-optimizations, however.

Answer (score 1):

This question is actual for me also... Because i am resolving this issue with:

```
var triggerParsers = function() {
    var val = ngModel.$viewValue; 
    ngModel.$setViewValue(null);
    ngModel.$setViewValue(val);
};
```

Comment: i believe the answer is do element.trigger('change');

Comment: I have tried use element.trigger, but this trick does not work, this is because the event was fired, but value was not changed therefore the angular does not launch the parsers.