# How do I set up my <input type="checkbox"> parser directive so Angular doesn’t overwrite it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a directive to set the model of a checkbox binding to a number instead of a bool:

```
module.directive('sjNumber', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attribute, $modelController) {
            $modelController.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
                return viewValue + 0;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

However, when I use this the model is always set to `true` or `false` after changing the checkbox value, instead of `1` or `0`.

I did some digging and found out that Angular’s built-in checkbox parser is inserted *after* my `link` function is run, at which point the `$parsers` array is empty. (The built-in parser is added in `checkboxInputType` on line 14945 of AngularJS v1.2.0-rc.3.)

How can I make this work?

Comment: Can't you just use the `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` attributes?  Like `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="someVal" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" />`?  See the docs for `input[checkbox]`

Comment: Apparently that will only ever use string values. I could try convert those into numbers again with a directive, but then it’s come full circle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to trigger angular parsers without inputing anything in the field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284878/how-to-trigger-angular-parsers-without-inputing-anything-in-the-field)