# How to trigger $parsers when model value changes in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive which has a $parsers and changes numbers to latin characters.

```
accountingApp.directive('toLatinNumber', function () {
  return {
     restrict: 'A',
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(inputValue){
           return toLatinNumber(toPersianNumber(inputValue));
        });
     }
  };
});
```

And There is a controller that changes and input which has `to-latin-number` directive and `vm.year` ng-model. this is how controller looks like:

```
vm.year = [something];
```

The problem is, when the code sets `vm.year`, $parsers doesn't trigger, but if I put something in the inout manually, it does trigger.

How can I trigger $parsers from **controller**? or maybe somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like below, add *$parsers* functions to *$formatters* as well. This way any model update will go thru formatters, invalid values are **filtered**, **validity** of the model will be set and invalid model values **won't be displayed** in view.

```js
function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
    ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(valid);
    ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(valid);

    function valid(viewValue) {
        var valid = isViewValueValid(viewValue);
        ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('valid', valid);
        if (valid) {
            return viewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284878/how-to-trigger-angular-parsers-without-inputing-anything-in-the-field) put, you can trigger it via:

```
parser($modelValue);
```